# Media Queries not taking affect.

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make the width of my footer img (social media icons) bigger on mobile. But when I change the width in the media query, nothing happens. I change the width in the original css with the 'footer img' and it works. Then I think I realized that none of my media queries are working. Why aren't my media queries taking effect?

```
ORIGINAL CSS

footer img {
  width: 40px;
}

a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: #0077C0;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 25px;
}

h4 {
  margin: 0px 125px 0px 125px;
}

.alignleft {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.alignright {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 15px;
  height: 30%;
}

MEDIA QUERIES {
/*iPhone 6/7/8 and iPad*/
@media (max-width: 450px) {
  #index {
    background-position: 41% 59%;
  }

  .grid-container {
    height: 100vh;

  }

  .grid-item {
    font-size: 25px;
  }

  .name {
    font-size: 32px;

  }

  .grid-item img {
    max-height: 70%;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .WhiteHouse img {
    max-height: 55%;
  }

  .alignleft {
    float: none;
    text-align: center;

  }

  .alignright {
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 7%;
  }

  #GitHub {
    width: 25%;
  }

footer img {
  width: 50%;
}


}
```

Comment: where are you even checking it with a `maximum width` of `450px`?

Comment: @ZombieChowder at `@media (max-width: 450px)`? it is in the code

Comment: Can you create a simplified example to show this? As it looks now, it should be working

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]. The code you've supplied appears to be neither minimal, nor complete.

Answer (score 4):

Dont wrap your media queries in MEDIA QUERIES {}

Also try putting this inside your head tag on the html page.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```